# retrieve the client certificate chain from an ISAPI request

Tags: c, iis, x509certificate, isapi

I would like to retrieve the entire client certificate chain from a request in ISAPI.

I already succeeded to get the first certificate in the client's certificate chain by invoking the code below:

```
LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK ecb_;

...

CERT_CONTEXT_EX cce;
memset(&cce, 0, sizeof(CERT_CONTEXT_EX));
char certbuf[64*1024];
cce.cbAllocated = sizeof(certbuf);
cce.CertContext.pbCertEncoded = (BYTE *) &certbuf;
ecb_->ServerSupportFunction(ecb_->ConnID, HSE_REQ_GET_CERT_INFO_EX, &cce, 0, 0)
```

However, I did not find out how to retrieve the rest of the certificate chain from this CERT_CONTEXT_EX struct.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this old question. I'm sorry I didn't see it sooner.

Many years ago I wrote a sample that shows how do do this using CAPICOM. Unfortunately CAPICOM is being phased out by Microsoft, though it still works.

I found the old isapiCertPolicy sample on Koders:

http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid977D79B2C51AD2423E4F57B6B36C3806F167CF79.aspx

Here are the relevant code fragments:

```
#import "capicom.dll"

char CertificateBuf[8192];
CERT_CONTEXT_EX ccex;
ccex.cbAllocated = sizeof(CertificateBuf);
ccex.CertContext.pbCertEncoded = (BYTE*)CertificateBuf;
ccex.dwCertificateFlags = 0;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(ccex);

fOk = pCtxt->ServerSupportFunction(
    (enum SF_REQ_TYPE)HSE_REQ_GET_CERT_INFO_EX,
    (LPVOID)&ccex,
    &dwSize,
    NULL);

_bstr_t bstrCert(
    SysAllocStringLen(
        (OLECHAR * )ccex.CertContext.pbCertEncoded,
        (ccex.CertContext.cbCertEncoded+1)/2),
    FALSE);

CAPICOM::ICertificate2Ptr Cert(__uuidof(CAPICOM::Certificate));
Cert->Import(bstrCert);

CAPICOM::IChainPtr Chain(__uuidof(CAPICOM::Chain));
BOOL fOk = Chain->Build(Cert);

CAPICOM::ICertificatesPtr Certs(NULL);
Certs = Chain->Certificates;

CAPICOM::ICertificate2Ptr ParentCert(Certs->Item[2])
```

The Chain object builds the certificate chain. If you can't use CAPICOM, you can get the certificate chain using the Crypto API's CertGetCertificateChain function, but it's more work.